# Algebraic manipulation of $Var(Y|X)=E[(Y-E(Y|X))^2|X]$

Tags: self-study, variance, expected-value

Q: Show that $Var(Y|X)=E[(Y-E(Y|X))^2|X]$ is equal to $Var(Y|X)=E[Y^2|X]-(E[Y|X)]^2$.

Answer: I know I have to use the law of iterated expectation to get to the second statement but I am having trouble with that. I understand that $E[E(Y|X)]=E[Y]$ but how can I use that to solve this problem?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no iterated expectation there, since everything is conditional to $X$. This is simply the definition of the variance for the conditional distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just expand the first expression (i.e. $(Y - E(Y \mid X))^2$) and use that $E(E(Y \mid X) \mid X) = E(Y \mid X)$.

Comment: Can you please give a bit more hint as how to expand the first expression? Like just multiply it out since the term is squared? Thanks!

Comment: Yes indeed: $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$